# define в if C++

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Есть такой код:

```
int main(){
  if(true){
    #define some awesomeness
  }
}
```

Что заменит define и где? В коде только после define, верно?

Comment: Такие вопросы проще проверить самому, чем ждать чьего-то ответа :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, `define` заменяют только те вхождения, которые описаны после них. Для того, чтобы это проверить, можно воспользоваться флагом компиляции, который запускает только препроцессор (для clang и gcc это `-E`):

```
$ cat main.cpp
int main(){
    some;

    if(true){
        #define some awesomeness
    }

    some;
}

$ clang++ -E main.cpp
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 320 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp" 2
int main(){
    some;

    if(true){

    }

    awesomeness;
}
```

Хотелось бы также отметить, что `if(true)` никак не влияет на определение `define`, поскольку сначала в любом случае запускается препроцессор.

---

У компилятора VS тоже существует опция запуска препроцессора (флаг `/E`):

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin> .\cl.exe E:\main.cpp /E
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30501 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
#line 1 "E:\\main.cpp"
int main(){
    some;

    if(true){

    }

    awesomeness;
}
```

Comment: А у VS есть такая возможность?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, ключ `/P` или Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File.

Answer (score 3):

Препроцессор ничего не знает о синтаксисе C или C++, для него код - это просто текст. `define` действует только на текст после себя.

Answer (score 3):

> Что заменит define и где? В коде только после define, верно?

Всё вхождения `some` между `#define some` и `#undef some`. Или до конца, если такого нет.

Расположение в структуре кода не имеет значения.